# Regarding the use of the present perfect tense

Tags: meaning, sentence, present-perfect

What tense is being used in the following sentences?

> - I have been here.
> - How often have you been in love in your life?
> - There has been an accident.

I think these sentences use the present perfect tense. My first question regarding the first example: Is *been* being used as a past particle or as a helping verb? If so, my second question is: What part of speech is *here*?

By the way, I took my first two examples from Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage*, and the third from a book on grammar by Raymond Murph (all three are covered under "present perfect").

Comment: Yes, the three sentences are using the present perfect. // However, I'm not sure about what you ask.

Comment: "been" in No. (1), (3) is never a helping verb. It is only in No. (2). Now, you need to read your question again and fix typos and be specific about your question. Your question is very difficult to understand.

Comment: @rhetorician Nice edit!

Comment: Do you mean What part of speech is ***here***?

Comment: After doing some search, I think *here* could be an attribute. Consider *here* as *at this place*.

Comment: I just want to know in my examples. What type of "been" is playing role in sentences as past particle or what and also what is verb,adverb etc in my examples and please make a post on been word usage stonyb like general use